# how template engine interact with drupal 7 core to display web page

Tags: php, drupal-7, template-engine, drupal-theming

i am *intermediate* in drupal.i start learning drupal 7 theme system. i need to know how template engine handle **php,html/css** inside its template files and its interaction with core system to make its final output as **webpage**.Means when we load drupal web page in browser what template engine do.what is the main role of template engine in drupal front end designing?. if anyone provide web link for working of template engine inside drupal system it will be great

thanks in advance..

Comment: This is hardly the type of question that this site is for.

Answer (score 2):

Template engines in Drupal are software components that combine Data from Drupal with Templates from themes and show the result -which is final HTML- to the user.

```
    +-----------+        +----------------+
    | Data from |        | Templates from |
    |  Drupal   |        |     theme      |
    +-----------+        +----------------+
          |                       |
          v      +--------+       v
          +------| Theme  |-------+
                 | Engine |
                 +--------+
                     |
                     v
              +-------------+
              |  Final HTML |
              +-------------+
```

so main question is
Why Drupal uses theme engines? Because different developers have different coding tastes and Drupal does not want to deal with different template "coding styles" directly.

If you are learning Drupal theme design, you do not need to know theme engine design. Now a days, almost all Drupal themes use one engine: PHPTemplate which -in my opinion- is brilliant. You only need to know the theme engine API if you want to design advanced themes. For basic usage, even API knowledge is not a must.